# How do I have searches I didn’t do on my phone?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

[image]

Google maps keeps saying I’m in places I haven’t been. It’s causing issues in my marriage  could my phone be hacked? There’s some random name that appears here and there from India. It shows I’ve been all over the Middle East and I don’t even have a passport !!! What do I do?

Comment: Search history is not an indicator of where you”ve been, just what you looked for.  Go into your Google account and look up your location data.  

Then, start using Apple Maps.  Use anything but Google.

Comment: Also, if you are logged into your Google account on several devices, search history gets synced between them.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me understand this. It’s in my google maps timeline and that is also where some random persons name appears. It even had purchasing tickets to India!!! My husband has already packed a bag and will not listen to reason! Idk what to do or how to prove I’m innocent! Additionally someone during this time has got my email as it’s been on the dark web several times this past year which is when this all started.